# How to rename container name in cryptoki

Tags: c++, cryptography, pkcs#11, cryptoapi, mscapi

I have write some code that writes keypair of public and private key in a token. From the keypair, I create pkcs10 and later generate certificate file from it. The certificate file will be inserted to the token. It all run successfully, but somehow the certificate cannot being read by CAPI or Internet Explorer. If i insert a p12 file, it run without a fuss. I suspect that the CKA_LABEL and CKA_ID is the culprit here. In p12, everything use the same name convention. From container, public key, private key, and certificate. However in my method, the container name looks like auto generated. How can i convert it to be same with CKA_ID? Down below is my code in generating keypair that save in container.

```
rv = g_pFunctionList->C_GenerateKeyPair(hSession,
        &ck_gen_ecc,
        tPubKey, sizeof(tPubKey) / sizeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE),
        tPrvKey, sizeof(tPrvKey) / sizeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE),
        &pkcs11_hPubKey, &pkcs11_hPrvKey);
```

It save in container name like

> cont_4440xxxxxxxx

How to change the container name as exactly as CKA_ID ? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cryptoki library allow it, you can rename all the objects by setting new properties of them by calling `C_SetAttributeValue` function.

In your case it can looks like this:

```
        CK_ATTRIBUTE atAttr[2];

        atAttr[0].type = CKA_LABEL;
        atAttr[0].pValue = pLabelValue;    // <-- pass here new Label value pointer
        atAttr[0].ulValueLen = ulLabelLen; // <-- pass here new Label length

        atAttr[1].type = CKA_ID;
        atAttr[1].pValue = pIDValue;    // <-- pass here new ID value pointer
        atAttr[1].ulValueLen = ulIDLen; // <-- pass here new ID length

        rv = g_pFunctionList->C_SetAttributeValue(hSession, pkcs11_hPubKey, atAttr, 2);
        rv = g_pFunctionList->C_SetAttributeValue(hSession, pkcs11_hPrvKey, atAttr, 2);
```

Comment: CKA_ID and CKA_LABEL has the same string. the public and private already is the same, i want to rename the container name to use the string. perhaps thay why the certificate cannot being read by CAPI or PKCS lib though. however i found a forum which said that the thing that i want to make is defined by the token provider library, so am writing code doing it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: From my experience Label is human readable and have suffix like 'Public Key', 'Private Key', 'Certificate', CKA_ID is declared as byte array and can be anything binary that can be easily constructed. In my case it was internal system identifier.

Comment: Seems like i cannot make it though. i would like to contact you, is it fine? if so, can i have your skype id or something? if you are a private person, you can email me kalassama1[at]gmail[dot]com. i do hope to fix this as soon as i can.thank you

Comment: I will mail you later.